# Accessing ViewModel instance

Tags: c++, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I am pretty new to MVVM and C++ (managed), and am trying to access my viewmodel object outside of the MainPage constructor.

```
MainPage::MainPage()
{   
     InitializeComponent();

    //Create ViewModel object
    ViewModel ^myViewModel;                                             
    myViewModel = ref new ViewModel;

}

ref class ViewModel 
{

    ViewModel::ViewModel() //Constructor
    {                            
        //Create array
        const size_t SIZE = 6;
        Point arr[SIZE];
    }

    void ViewModel::doDraw()
    {
    }


   void profileDisplay::MainPage::myButton_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
    {
        myViewModel->doDraw();
    }
}
```

Visual Studio Intellisense reports that my myViewModel under my _Click event is undefined. This seems like it would be a basic problem, but I seem to be hung up on it. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You should declare `myViewModel` as a member of the MainPage class instead of a local variable in the MainPage constructor. Besides that you'll usually assign the view model instance to the Page's DataContext property.

Comment: That was it. I didn't realize that declaring my pointer inside the constructor would cause that. Thanks!